# Edit movie in Rails edits all movie objects instead of the one in question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a movie list app where I can create lists and add movies to them. I have a form to edit a movie, but when I submit the form, it updates all movie objects in the list instead of just the selected one. I'm stumped as to why this is happening and could use a second set of eyes.

My button on the list show page that takes me to the form for editing a movie:

```
<%= button_to "Edit movie", edit_movie_path(m), method: 'get', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-space' %>
```

My edit and update controller actions in movies_controller.rb:

```
  def edit
   @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie = Movie.update(movie_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

And my form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @movie do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "Movie Title", input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <%= f.input :year, as: :date,
            start_year: Date.today.year,
            end_year: Date.today.year - 100, 
            discard_day: true, discard_month: true, order: [:year], 
            input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <%= f.input :genre, placeholder: "Genre", input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.input :poster, placeholder: "Poster URL", input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <%= f.input :director, placeholder: "Director",
            input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <%= f.input :rating, collection: 1..5, prompt: "1(bad) - 5(great)", input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.association :lists, as: :check_boxes, multiple: true, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :plot, as: :text, placeholder: "Plot Summary", input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Add Movie", class: "btn btn-primary col-md-4" %> 
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
def edit
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  @movie = Movie.update(movie_params)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Should be:

```
def edit
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  @movie.update(movie_params)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

You can notice that `Movie.update` has changed to `@movie.update`. This is because `Movie.update` will update every single record in `movies` table in your database. while `@movie.update` will only update the selected movie from `@movie = Movie.find(params[:id])`.

I hope this helps you and make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

`Movie.update(movie_params)` will fire sql query to update all records of `Movie` model, to update a single record it need to call update on that object only. hope fully it's clear to you.

```
  def update
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie = @movie.update(movie_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```